# Override pallet struct fields without implementing a new pallet

Tags: pallet, identity, coupling

I am using the Substrate Identity pallet, and I would like to change the profile fields that are included as default (twitter, riot, email, legal, etc). I understand that there are additional fields, but these are ones that are known at compile time.

If I want to replace those fields with my own, do I need to implement my own pallet? Can I use coupling in a way so that I don't need to override that one Struct?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Identity pallet is not designed to accept an alternative identity info struct, so your best bet in this case is to implement your own pallet.